# ListView only printing last position

Tags: android, listview, adapter

So... I'm having a strange problem with CustomAdapter, here's my code:

```
public class QuilometragemCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Quilometragem> quilometragens;
    Quilometragem km;

    public QuilometragemCustomAdapter(Context context, List<Quilometragem> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.quilometragens = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return quilometragens.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Quilometragem getItem(int position) {

        return quilometragens.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        int color = Color.argb(255,41,36,33);
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.veiculoTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.veiculoTxt);
            holder.destinoTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dmTxt);
            holder.imageB = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
            holder.imageB2 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
            TextView txtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            TextView txtD = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
            txtV.setText("\nVeiculo:\n");
            txtD.setText("\nDestino:\n");
            holder.imageB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_edit);
            holder.imageB2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.nkm =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.nkm.setText("\n" + quilometragens.get(position).getId()+ "\n");

        String veiculoTxt = quilometragens.get(position).getVeiculo();
        holder.veiculoTxt.setText("\n\n" + veiculoTxt + "           \n");
        holder.veiculoTxt.setTextColor(color);

        String destinoTxt = quilometragens.get(position).getDestino();
        holder.destinoTxt.setText("\n" + destinoTxt + "\n");
        holder.destinoTxt.setTextColor(color);

        return convertView;
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
            private TextView veiculoTxt;
            private TextView destinoTxt;
            private ImageButton imageB;
            private ImageButton imageB2;
            private TextView nkm;

    }
  }
```

I'm not using a list, i made a layout just for the rows, so i could add it as i insert data in the sqlite database, but it's still with the same problem.

The thing is, my layout is printing only the last position, i debugged it like, a thousand times and my "position" starts always at 0 and keeps incrementing as i have items in the list.
If i have 3 items in the list, like: ABC 123     QWE 321    IOP   456
it always prints the "IOP 456" it's like the other 2 are not there, i tried with a for but the results were worse, i tried with a do()while, and it got even worse. I think the problem is with the View, but i'm not really sure.

Comment: try to use arraylist and get position..cuz its replace position in your code

Comment: Share all your adapter class

Comment: What print? I dont see any println statement and you didn't set that tag in the if block. You are only getting the tag but not saving it

Comment: `convertView.setTag(holder)` is missing in the if block

Comment: Ok, i did put the full class in the edit and set the tag but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call 
    convertView.setTag(mHolder);
at the end of if condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
{
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView veiculoTxt;
        private TextView destinoTxt;
        private ImageButton imageB;
        private ImageButton imageB2;
        private TextView nkm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        int color = Color.argb(255,41,36,33);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        }

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.veiculoTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.veiculoTxt);
            holder.destinoTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dmTxt);
            holder.imageB = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
            holder.imageB2 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
            TextView txtV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            TextView txtD = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
            txtV.setText("\nVeiculo:\n");
            txtD.setText("\nDestino:\n");
            holder.imageB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_edit);
            holder.imageB2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel);
            holder.nkm =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.nkm.setText("\n" + quilometragens.get(position).getId()+ "\n");

        String veiculoTxt = quilometragens.get(position).getVeiculo();
        holder.veiculoTxt.setText("\n\n" + veiculoTxt + "           \n");
        holder.veiculoTxt.setTextColor(color);

        String destinoTxt = quilometragens.get(position).getDestino();
        holder.destinoTxt.setText("\n" + destinoTxt + "\n");
        holder.destinoTxt.setTextColor(color);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still printing the last item.